# Legend is stuck on startup()

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, legend, feature-layer

All my layer URLs and Feature Layers are stored in an array.

with an foreach loop, I am creating the FeatureLayers from the URLs,

```
dojo.forEach(window.layerUrls, function (info, idx) {
            window.featureLayers[idx] = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(
            window.layerUrls[idx], {
                infoTemplate: infoTemplate,
                mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
                outFields: window.outFields
            }
          );
            map.addLayers([window.featureLayers[idx]]);
        });
```

This is the code to generate the legend:

```
dojo.connect(window.map, 'onLayersAddResult', function (results) {
            var legendDiv = dijit.byId('legendDiv');
            if (legendDiv) {
                legendDiv.destroyRecursive(true);
            }
            var layerInfo = dojo.map(results, function (layer, index) {
                return { layer: layer.layer, title: layer.layer.name };
            });

            var legendDijit = new esri.dijit.Legend({
                map: map,
                layerInfos: layerInfo
            }, 'legendDiv');
            legendDijit.startup();

        });
```

Whe I run the page this is what the legend looks like and I have no idea why:
http://abload.de/img/legend22uj3.jpg
Here is the code related to this picture:

```
<div id="legendDiv_graphicsLayer6" class="esriLegendService" style="display: block;">
<div id="legendDiv_graphicsLayer4" class="esriLegendService" style="display: block;">
<div id="legendDiv_graphicsLayer3" class="esriLegendService" style="display: block;">
<div id="legendDiv_graphicsLayer5" class="esriLegendService" style="display: block;">
<div id="legendDiv_graphicsLayer2" class="esriLegendService" style="display: block;">
<div id="legendDiv_graphicsLayer1" class="esriLegendService" style="display: block;">
<div id="legendDiv_msg" style="display: none;">Keine Legende vorhanden</div>
<div id="legendDiv_msg">Legende wird erstellt...</div>
<div id="legendDiv_msg">Legende wird erstellt...</div>
<div id="legendDiv_msg">Legende wird erstellt...</div>
<div id="legendDiv_msg">Legende wird erstellt...</div>
<div id="legendDiv_msg">Legende wird erstellt...</div>
```

Additonally: when zooming the legend disappears and only one random FeatureLayer-legend remains

Where did I go wrong and why?

Answer (score 1):

The [legend's layerInfos property](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/legend.html) has to be an array. You are passing in a function.

You're also attempting to create the legend on each loop iteration. What you want to do is loop through your feature layers and create an array that you can pass to layerInfos. The [basic legend widget sample](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/widget_legend.html) shows this using dojo.map. Adapting your code to do this would look something like this:

```
var layerInfos = dojo.map(window.featureLayers, function(layer) {
  return { layer: layer, title: layer.name };
});
var legend = new esri.dijit.Legend({
  map: map,
  layerInfos: layerInfos
}, "legendDiv");
legend.startup();
```

Note that you should do this after the feature layers have been added to the map so it's a good idea to use map.addLayers() and onLayersAddResult which is also shown in the sample linked above.

Comment: I incorporated these changes on my own, however the problem persists. I am getting the legend PLUS "legend is being created..." like in the screenshot
/edit: updated original code

Comment: Please post a more complete code sample to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I will post the complete code as it is on monday.